# append two methods in flickr

Tags: php, flickr

I have to use two methods from Flickr to achieve my desired result; "the photos.search method" returns the photo id while the "geo.getLocation method" returns the long and lat value of each photo id.
I am able to successfully iterate my search to get each photo id within my search area. My question is how do I iterate each photo id in the "geo.getLocation method" so as to get their latitude and longitude values.

Find below my php code that returns each photo id:

```
<?php

$url = ("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=ff8c4c178209865b1ac5ee3f2d492de0&lat=51.5424&lon=-0.1734&radius=2&page=1&text=flats");

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($xml->photos->photo as $entry) {  
echo $entry->attributes()->id;
echo $entry->attributes()->owner;
echo $entry->attributes()->title; 
}

?>
```

The REST request format for the geo.getLocation method is:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.geo.getLocation&api_key=xxxx&photo_id=[value]
```

Yemi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not get each location as you iterate over the photo ids, as in

```
<?php

$url = ("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=ff8c4c178209865b1ac5ee3f2d492de0&lat=51.5424&lon=-0.1734&radius=2&page=1&text=flats");

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($xml->photos->photo as $entry) {  
   echo $entry->attributes()->id;
   echo $entry->attributes()->owner;
   echo $entry->attributes()->title;
   $xmlloc = simplexml_load_file("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.geo.getLocation&api_key=xxxx&photo_id=" . $entry->attributes()->id);
// process XML file
}

?>
```

Comment: I implemented your edit and it keeps returning the error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\...\search.php on line 11.. (Line 11 is your line of edit)

Comment: That's a timeout problem with the API, not a problem with the code.  How many photos are you downloading - it could be that you've exceeded an API limit.

Comment: I parsed the per_page argument to (50) to reduce the result size and it didn't return any errors again. So I guess you're right, but please how do I echo the latitude and longitude values that are being returned?

Comment: I've changed the variable name inside the loop to $xmlloc, since $xml is the variable you're using to control the loop.  Try printing out $xmlloc->photo->location->attributes()->latitude (and the same thing for longitude).  Finally, please consider upvoting the answer.

Comment: It worked. Sure I was going to do that as soon as it was resolved. Thanks